# How can I unset the session of a specific user?

Tags: php, session-management

I have a session like this `$_SESSION['login']` and when it is equal with `1`, it means the use is logged into my website:

```
if ( $_SESSION['login'] == 1 ) {
    // You are logged
} else {
    // login/register
}
```

Also I have another session which contains user's id. Something like this:

```
echo $_SESSION["Id"]; 
/* It is containing the user's id (an integer number).
   Something like: 234124
*/
```

Now I want to unset `$_SESSION['login']` for the user who has a specific id. For example I want to `unset($_SESSION['login'])` for `$_SESSION["Id"] = 234124`. How can I do that?

---

**Edit:** All I'm trying to do: When an user changes his password, I remove all his cookies from `cookies` table to sign him out from all his other devices. Also I want to remove his session.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your right, you want to sign out a user completely, i.e. from all sessions (from a laptop, a mobile phone, etc.).

It's only possible when 1) you have a mapping `user_id => session_id` and 2) you can query sessions somehow. For example, when you store sessions in a database table, and you have user_id as a column in this table, you can simply delete all sessions for a user (or just modify them).

But it's not possible with default PHP session handler. You don't have such type of mapping available.

I advise you to write [a custom session handler](http://php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php) that stores sessions in a database table. To build the mapping, you can override [`write` method](http://php.net/manual/en/sessionhandler.write.php) and extract your `user_id` there. Be careful with serialized data, pay attention to [`session.serialize_handler` configuration directive](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.serialize-handler).

For example,

php.ini

```
session.serialize_handler = php_serialize
```

session handler

```
public function write($id, $data)
{
    $content = unserialize($data);

    return $this->db->insert('sessions', [
        'id' => $id,
        'user_id' => $content['user_id'],
        'data' => $data,
    ]);
}
```

and control code

```
if (...) {
    $db->execute('DELETE FROM sessions WHERE user_id = ?', $userId);
}
```